# Linux Installation Copy & Version Upgrading

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, installation, upgrade

1. I had installed an ubuntu 10.04 to a pen drive of mine. Now, I want to move it to a pen drive with bigger storage. But, how/what software should I use to do that?
2. Is is possible to upgrade from 10.04 to 11.04 or 11.10, without any problem? I heard only LTS supports upgrade among themselves, otherwise its not possible. Is it true?

Comment: Can you split this off into 2 questions? The system works best when there's one post per question.

Comment: I would do from the next time! :) thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would backup and restore your USB disk image using instructions as described in this [link](http://theseekersquill.wordpress.com/2009/07/18/linux-manage-usbpendrive/).

Then I would adjust the persistent storage size using instructions such as described [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-create-a-larger-casper-rw-loop-file/).

To upgrade, you must upgrade in order i.e. 10.04 to 10.10 to 11.04 etc.  Canonical only supports this route between LTS versions.

You will be able to move from one LTS version to another in one go since this will be a supported route i.e. 10.04 to 12.04.

Attempting to circumvent these recommendations is definitely not recommended - you could end up with broken packages, files not upgraded or incorrectly modified resulting in a system which would behave erratically, or even just not boot.

Comment: So, I can jump from one LTS to another one without any problem. Other then that, I have to go through each release.

Comment: Correct - Canonical only support the upgrade routes described ... and  I've also seen the problems when people ignore the support routes and try to jump releases e.g. jumping from 10.04 to 11.04.  Definitely not a recommended way to upgrade.

Comment: things are clear to me now :) but can you tell me something about the issues that occurs, when people break the chain?

Comment: iamcreasy - have added to my answer.